# how to pass argument (file path) to python app in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a python application that is expecting first argument as file path. basically a configuration file.

This file it should get form volume/ mount in Docker

How to pass this:

. Snippets
Python:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
```

Docker file

```
COPY install.py /wiki/install.py
CMD [ "python", "/wiki/install.py", "/config/config.yml"]
```

Run image command

```
sudo docker run -v /config:/home/example/config/ app-wiki
```

I am expecting config.yml file available at /home/example/config/ will be copied in /config dir and inside Docker file
it will be available

but its not working this way.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: I got hint from your response. 
I am expecting config file as argument to install.py. This path I want from volume. So I created a volume by name wikiconfig.  
 docker volume create wikiconfig

and then assigning this volume to

 sudo docker run -v /wikiconfig:/home/example/config/ app-wiki

Now using 
 CMD [ "python", "/agent/install.py", "/wikiconfig/config.yml"]

This also won't wo

Answer (score 0):

The way docker `CMD` works is you need to make sure that the file is copied into the correct location with correct permissions.

Example:

```
RUN mkdir -p /config
RUN mkdir -p /wiki
ADD cp <your-location> /config/config.yml
ADD install.py /wiki/install.py
CMD [ "python", "/wiki/install.py", "/config/config.yml"]
```

Also, docker will keep the same permissions that you have in your local directory. So, make sure you have correct permission set on both files.

Comment: I am expecting config file as argument to install.py. This path I want from volume.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have got the direction wrong. The format is `<hostpath>:<containerpath>`

Below

```
sudo docker run -v /config:/home/example/config/ app-wiki
```

should be

```
sudo docker run -v /home/example/config/:/config app-wiki
```

Doing the config present in `/home/example/config/` will be available in container at `/config` folder

**Edit-1**

Added a bit of more explanation to clear you doubts.

```
COPY install.py /wiki/install.py
CMD [ "python", "/wiki/install.py", "/config/config.yml"]
```

When you run the above image it will expect a config to be available at `/config/config.yml`.

Now if you have a folder on your host `/home/tarun/wikiconfig` which has a `config.yml` file then you run the container using

```
sudo docker run -v /home/tarun/wikiconfig:/config app-wiki
```

If the name of the `config.yml` file is different in your `wikiconfig` folder, then you will mount the file to `config.yml`

```
sudo docker run -v /home/tarun/wikiconfig/myconfig.yml:/config/config.yml app-wiki
```

Both would override the config you added when you build the Dockerfile, because when you a mount a folder or file from host, anything with the same path inside container is no more accessible to the image

Comment: I got hint from your response. 
I am expecting config file as argument to install.py. This path I want from volume. So I created a volume by name wikiconfig.  
 docker volume create wikiconfig

and then assigning this volume to

 sudo docker run -v /wikiconfig:/home/example/config/ app-wiki

Now using 
 CMD [ "python", "/agent/install.py", "/wikiconfig/config.yml"]

This also won't work

Comment: again your volume order is wrong. `/wikiconfig:/home/example/config/` should be `/home/example/config/:/wikiconfig`

Comment: What should be used in Docker file to access this config file?

Comment: I want configuration stored at /home/example/config/ the mount point to be used in Docker file to pass to python app as argument

Comment: Yeah. thanks it works. But I have another confusion. I want to deploy the same image in two vms. in docker I am referring to config file using mount point.  Now how to ensure that all container started uses same configuration file.